# Xamarin iOS UISlider AddTarget EventHandler No UIEvent Parameter

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin

I am trying to convert some swift code I found for detecting when the UISlider control dragging the thumb started and then when it ended into Xamarin.iOS C#.  But the EventHandler for the Xamarin.iOS code doesn't pass the UIEvent parameter.

Swift:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSliderValChanged(slider:event:)), for: .valueChanged)


@objc func onSliderValChanged(slider: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {
if let touchEvent = event.allTouches?.first {
    switch touchEvent.phase {
    case .began:
        // handle drag began
    case .moved:
        // handle drag moved
    case .ended:
        // handle drag ended
    default:
        break
    }
}
}
```

C#

```
 slider.AddTarget(HandleEventHandler, UIControlEvent.ValueChanged);

 void HandleEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //TODO
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different from swift, xamarin.ios is based on OC. UISlider click event is not allowed to take multiple parameters, the only parameter is the default UISlider itself. If you want to distinguish between different states. You can `addTarget` in different states.

```
slider.AddTarget(this,new Selector("SliderValueChange:"),UIControlEvent.ValueChanged);
slider.AddTarget(this,new Selector("SliderTouchStart:"), UIControlEvent.TouchDown);
slider.AddTarget(this,new Selector("SliderTouchEnded:"), UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);

[Export("SliderValueChange:")]
public void SliderValueChange(UISlider sender)
 {

    Console.WriteLine(sender.Value);

 }


[Export("SliderTouchStart:")]
public void SliderTouchStart(UISlider sender)
 {

    Console.WriteLine("start");

 }

[Export("SliderTouchEnded:")]
public void SliderTouchEnded(UISlider sender)
 {

    Console.WriteLine("end");

 }
```